# DataDog processing colorized logs with ANSI escape sequences

Tags: datadog

I am trying to monitor MySQL and Python application logs, but it seems as though 50% or moreof the logs have embedded ANSI escape sequences to prettify them for CLI consumption.  This causes the pipeline processors to fail in DataDog.  Is there any way to deal with this?

I was expecting to see properly formatted logs or perhaps some guidance in the log analytics docs, but as a new DataDog user, I am finding the docs somewhat overwhelming, especially when trying to deploy DataDog at a small company with containerized applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could solve this, but my suggestion is to strip out ANSI sequences at the agent configuration level, using the [`mask_sequences`](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/?tab=configurationfile#scrub-sensitive-data-from-your-logs) feature. The use case presented in the docs is for redacting information, but you can use a blank placeholder if you just want to remove. If it's useful for you, you could instead use a note saying ANSI was removed.

For your pattern, you'll need to find a way to put the actual escape character into your string. It looks like `\[` here on SO but it's a special character. You can see the ESC character (and should be able to copy/paste) from this [grokdebugger link](https://grokdebugger.com/?pattern=(%3F%3A%1B%5C%5B%5B0-9%5Dm%5BMnNfFbB%5D%3F)&sample=%1B%5B1mB).

Replacing that char with the ESC char, the pattern I'd start with is `\[[0-9]{1,3}m[MnNfFbB]?`.

Hopefully this is enough to get you pointed the right way!